# Unable to display pie chart from array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looping over a series but it is not working, so I am looking for any other alternative solution.

My array is working fine but not able to map that array to a Highcharts pie chart.

```js
var mssg = ["total more than 400","total less than 400 and greater than 300","total less than 300"];

arr4.length=8;

var percent=[22.33,44.33,33.33];

// code to push values into array series1 
for (var i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
  series1.push({
    name: mssg[i],
    y: percent[i]
  });

}

// highchartcode
Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Pie chart according to total'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Total',
    colorByPoint: true,

    data: series1
   

  }]
});
```

Comment: can you post your full code in the snippet, it's giving error.

Comment: your data length is 3 but you set the arr4.length to 8, this will add lots of undefineds which could break the chart.

Comment: You should see the `undefined` errors mentioned by @Ekim in the console, along with any other errors that are stopping your chart from being displayed.